# Having AssertionError when using NLTK KMeans Clustering

Tags: cluster-computing, nltk, k-means

I am trying to use the NLTK KMeans Cluster to cluster some vectors. I have some 10-dimension vectors, when I tried to cluster them, NLTK sometimes gives errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yhz82415/workspace/Grouping/src/Driver.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/yhz82415/workspace/Grouping/src/Driver.py", line 20, in main
    KMeans(numClusters, dictionary)
  File "/home/yhz82415/workspace/Grouping/src/Tools.py", line 78, in KMeans
    clusters=clusterer.cluster(vectors, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/cluster/util.py", line 51, in cluster
    self.cluster_vectorspace(vectors, trace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/cluster/kmeans.py", line 70, in cluster_vectorspace
    self._cluster_vectorspace(vectors, trace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/cluster/kmeans.py", line 109, in _cluster_vectorspace
    new_means = map(self._centroid, clusters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/cluster/kmeans.py", line 149, in _centroid
    assert len(cluster) > 0
AssertionError
```

And the error does not always come out, sometimes it does, sometimes it does not.

I have tried the demo code, it works fine.

Anybody has hints?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen of the source code (though it might be a different version of nltk) it appears that the assert statement is in the function `_centroid`.  The purpose of this function is to calculate the centroid of a cluster.  If a cluster has no points, it would be meaningless to calculate a centroid so the very first line of `_centroid` checks against this condition.

Now, if a cluster has 0 points in it, it could mean any number of things depending upon what you are doing.  Maybe it is an error condition, maybe it means the cluster can be disposed of, maybe you want to repopulate this cluster with points from other clusters .... whatever.  So it is something the user might want to know, but it should not necessarily be handled as an error because it is not necessarily an error condition.

BTW, the copy of source I am examining is [this](http://svn.cs.brynmawr.edu/viewvc/Calico/trunk/bin/Lib/nltk/cluster/kmeans.py?view=markup&sortby=log)